# How to change the date format for the AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user on Windows?

Tags: windows

I have a scheduled task that executes a .NET Core application. The application counts on the system having a date format in en-GB or "DD/MM/YYYY". The scheduled task is set to run as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user.

Note: the above-scheduled task runs on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Is there a way to change the date format for the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user from Powershell in my User-Data script (i.e. when the EC2 instance boots)?

I have tried running this command in my user-data script:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sShortDate -Value dd/MM/yyyy
```

but it does not work. The reason is that the user-data is executed as the Administrator user (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work unless it is executed by a command prompt run as system, which you aren't doing. You need to set the registry value in the correct location:

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Control Panel\International`

[image: Regedit]

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. Also, would it be easy to set the same date format for all users on the system?